# Can I use continue statement from child function in python?

Tags: python

To clarify the what I want to do, I modified the question.

```
def main(): 
  for i in range(10): 
    sub1(i)
    sub2(i)
 
def sub1(i):
  if i == 5: 
    continue 
  else: 
    print(f'hello world from sub1')

def sub2(i):
  print(f'hello world from sub2')

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  main()
```

I would like to skip sub2 when i is 5.

When I run this script, I got error of `SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop`. Is it possible to call continue statement from child function? Is there any alternative way to do this ?

I want to use this syntax because of readability.

Comment: You can't do it exactly as you presented. But you can return from your function (`return` instead of `continue`), so that your inner function will end, and a new iteration in the `main` will begin

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can `return` from your inner function early, this can also be useful if you have many places at which you want to stop execution, e.g.

```
def main(): 
  for i in range(10): 
    sub(i)

def sub(i):
  if i == 5: return
  print(f'hello world!')
  if i < 10: return
  print('wow a big number')
```

**To your edited question:**

Speaking about code structure and readability, it's better if the decisions about the loop would be done where the loop is (not in the inner functions). I would personally do it this way

```
def main(): 
  for i in range(10):
    if i == 5: continue
    sub1(i)
    sub2(i)
 
def sub1(i):
  print(f'hello world from sub1')

def sub2(i):
  print(f'hello world from sub2')
```

Yet to fulfill your curiosity, I'll give you a workaround for your exact question:

```
def main(): 
  for i in range(10): 
    if sub1(i):
      sub2(i)
 
def sub1(i):
  if i == 5: 
    return False 
  print(f'hello world from sub1')
  return True

def sub2(i):
  print(f'hello world from sub2')
```

Comment: This answer is best option to deal with this. 

Thank you for comment and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
def main(): 
  for i in range(10): 
    sub(i)

def sub(i):
  if i != 5: 
    print(f'hello world!')
```

?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I modified the question a little bit. 
I would like to skip sub2 when i is 5 from sub1 function.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the if statement to to include everything other than when i is 5 then call sub2 from within sub1

```
def main(): 
  for i in range(10): 
    sub1(i)
    
 
def sub1(i):
  if i != 5: 
    print(f'hello world from sub1')
    sub2(i)


def sub2(i):
  print(f'hello world from sub2')

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  main()
```

Comment: Won't run, `continue` is called outside of the loop

Comment: Sorry yep, meant to have modified that if statement as well. I've modified the code thanks

Answer (score 0):

Continue Statement, You have to use it directly in a cycle.

The continue statement gives you the option to skip over the part of a loop where an external condition is triggered, but to go on to complete the rest of the loop. That is, the current iteration of the loop will be disrupted, but the program will return to the top of the loop.

The continue statement will be within the block of code under the loop statement, usually after a conditional if statement.

Using the same for loop program as in the Break Statement section above, we’ll use a continue statement rather than a break statement:

```
number = 0

for number in range(10):
    if number == 5:
        continue    # continue here

    print('Number is ' + str(number))

print('Out of loop')
```

The difference in using the continue statement rather than a break statement is that our code will continue despite the disruption when the variable number is evaluated as equivalent to 5. Let’s look at our output:

```
Output
Number is 0
Number is 1
Number is 2
Number is 3
Number is 4
Number is 6
Number is 7
Number is 8
Number is 9
Out of loop
```

Here, Number is 5 never occurs in the output, but the loop continues after that point to print lines for the numbers 6-10 before leaving the loop.

You can use the continue statement to avoid deeply nested conditional code, or to optimize a loop by eliminating frequently occurring cases that you would like to reject.

The continue statement causes a program to skip certain factors that come up within a loop, but then continue through the rest of the loop.